# Jmeter keeps crashing on MacOS with openjdk21

Tags: macos, jmeter, openjdk-21

I m trying to run jmeter 5.6.2 with openjdk21 and it keeps crashing. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/150824 I have gone through this and they have mentioend to update **/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jmeter/5.6.2/bin/jmeter** but I could not find this. anyone resolved this issue?

I have tried editing the Install_receipt.json and point to the java version 21, but It still crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue either using [Homebrew formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/jmeter) or using [normal manual JMeter installation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation):

[image]

You can try out the "manual" way:

1. Install [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/install)

   ```
   curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
   ```

   add `sdk` command to your PATH

   ```
   source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
   ```
2. Install [Java 21](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/java/announcing-microsoft-build-of-openjdk-21/)

   ```
   sdk install java 21.0.1-ms
   ```
3. Use it in the terminal:

   ```
   sdk use java 21.0.1-ms
   ```
4. Download JMeter 5.6.2

   ```
   wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.6.2.tgz
   ```
5. Unpack it

   ```
   tar xf apache-jmeter-5.6.2.tgz
   ```
6. Launch it

   ```
   ./apache-jmeter-5.6.2/bin/jmeter.sh
   ```

   JMeter GUI should appear, you can add [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to double check which Java version is being used.

Be aware that officially JMeter supports Java 17, higher versions can cause problems for example with [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it failed from step 4 downwards for some other error, but now i mable to atleast open up jmeter without crashing. (with my existing jmeter installation). Anyway if you suggest that java 17 is the version officially supported by Jmeter, i might try downgrading it to 17.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. It started working when I uninstalled jmeter using Homebrew, and installed it manually.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else gets the same error, please do as below. It worked for me non JMeter 5.6.3.
Navigate to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jmeter/5.6.2/bin/jmeter
Edit the file (user must have elevated privileges) from this:

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17" exec "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jmeter/${version}/libexec/bin/jmeter"  "$@"
```

To this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jmeter/${version}/libexec/bin/jmeter"  "$@"
```

Replace `${version}` with your JMeter version (e.g. 5.6.2)